# Há como escrever um função na tela que não seja por onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, o único modo que sei chamar uma função javascript no html é pelo onclick, mas meu html não é um botão para clicar, gostaria de saber se há outra forma de mostrar um função quando é chamada.

```
ex: onload -> para quando a tela carregar
onclick -> quando clicarem no elemento
```

tem alguma que apenas mostra?

Comment: tecnicamente não, apenas que apareça... tipo a tela inicializou ele está lá, mas como o código é bem no meio.. não sei se posso usar o onload..

Comment: Como assim "o código é bem no meio"? Pode [edit] e mostrar o trecho relevante do seu código?

Comment: O que você quer é chamar uma função ao carregar a página?

Comment: ele fica no meio, dentro de divs... o código inteirinho é muito extenso e oque eu preciso fica justo no meio dele..

Comment: se for uma função, basta executa-la assim: `exibirDados()`

Comment: sério? funciona mesmo... não preciso colocar dentro de nada?

Comment: só precisa estar dentro da tag script: `<script>minhaFuncao();</script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function fazerAlgo()
{
  //código aqui
}
// em alguma parte do seu código mais tarde...
fazerAlgo();
```

No HTML:

```
<script src="minhafuncao.js"></script>
<div id="">Em alguma parte do seu html</div>
<script>fazerAlgo();</script>
```

Comment: Simmm... Obrigadaaa... mas como faço para chamar esta função no html?

Comment: ela ficaria daquela forma também no html?

Comment: No HTML você devera colocar a tag script `<script>fazerAlgo();</script>` mas pra funcionar você deverá chamar o script que contém a função antes.

Comment: Só cuidado que se a função fizer referência a algum elemento do html, ele precisa existir no momento da chamada. Por isso recomenda-se colocar os scripts logo antes do fim do `<body>`.

Answer (score 3):

Na sua própria pergunta está uma das alternativas: no `onload`.

Se você **não** deseja chamar a função por meio de uma **ação direta** do usuário (um *click*, por exemplo), basta chamá-la de forma **explícita**, seja durante o carregamento da página, simplesmente chamando a função após o código da função:

```
<script>
function minhaFuncao(){
...
}
minhaFuncao();
</script>
```

Ou **após** o carregamento da página:

```
<script>
function minhaFuncao(){
...
}
window.onload = minhaFuncao;
</script>
```

Comment: Muito obrigada ...foi de grande ajuda as duas respostas, mas apenas posso marcar uma como certa. Sinto muito por não conseguir marcar a sua também .... >-<

Comment: @Alis Sim, claro. O importante não é marcar a resposta como certa, mas acrescentar algumas informações úteis. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 1):

Existem diversos Listener que podem ser usados, segue alguns exemplo e formas de aplicação com JavaScript puro:

```
document.addEventListener('click', suaFuncao(), true); // No Clique
document.addEventListener('load', suaFuncao(), true); // No load
document.addEventListener('resize', suaFuncao(), true); // No Resize
```

e para aplicá-los vamos supor, no click:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('classe ou id do seu botao');
btn.addEventListener('click', suaFuncao(), true);
```

Comment: Você está executando as funções e passando os retornos em vez das referências.

Comment: @bfavaretto pode me explicar melhor o que vc disse?

Comment: Quis dizer que precisaria ser `document.addEventListener('click', suaFuncao, true);`, sem os parênteses depois do nome da função.